# Xamarin Forms ListView ItemTapped to object from ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I have created a ListView with an ItemSource from my ViewModel. Now the ItemSource is an `ObservableCollection<KnownDevice>` with a few objects called `KnownDevice`. In my ListView I have set: `ItemTapped="rowDevice_Clicked"` with the following function:

```
private void rowDevice_Clicked(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView= (ListView)sender;
}
```

But now I need to know which KnownDevice was clicked.

How can I do that?

Comment: `e.Item` contains the tapped Item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line of code inside your **rowDevice_Clicked**

```
var device = e.Item as KnownDevice
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for xD

Answer (score 0):

just make another single instance of your KnownDevice

```
public ObservableCollection<KnownDevice> ThisIsMySelectionList {get; set;}
public KnownDevice ThisIsTheSelectedDeviceFromList {get; set;}
```

Then, in your list definition

```
<ListView 
   ItemsSource="{Binding ThisIsMySelectionList}"
   SelectedItem="{Binding ThisIsTheSelectedDeviceFromList}" >

   .. rest of your column definitions to show

</ListView>
```

As an item is tapped/selected from the list, it is bound to the public get/set of "ThisIsTheSelectedDeviceFromList" as bound to the SelectedItem value

I'm sure there are others who can point to a more direct way, but within your getter/setter, you can point to the app object yourself, such as

```
public KnownDevice ThisIsTheSelectedDeviceFromList 
{
   get { return ((YourNamespace.App)App).YourKnownDeviceProperty; }
   set {((YourNamespace.App)App).YourKnownDeviceProperty = value; }
}
```

So here, I am forcing a typecast to specifically YOUR App by qualifying your project namespace.app of the static app object, then your property.  You can get and set directly as needed.

Comment: Okay, but what if I want to bind it to for example to `App.selectedDevice` with as type `KnownDevice`?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk, see revised answer to point to some other object for the binding.

Comment: When I click on a row, the code doesn't hit my breakpoint on the following line: `set {((YourNamespace.App)App).YourKnownDeviceProperty = value; }`, so the SelectedDevice stays `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk, probably your binding context.  If the form/screen/page/ whatever does not have the BindingContext to your MVVM (view model) that all other components are connected to, it wont work...  You have not provided enough of the rest of your binding / data context.

Comment: Add your View Model and the App.selectedDeviceyou are refer here to your question @A.Vreeswijk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a property selectedDevice and bind that to SelectedItem of listview, below is my code hope it will be helpful for you.

ListView XAML :

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding KnownDeviceItems}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedKnownDevice}"
          SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    //code here for cell
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

ViewModel Properties :

```
private ObservableCollection<KnownDevice> knownDeviceItems;
    public ObservableCollection<KnownDevice> KnownDeviceItems
    {
        get { return knownDeviceItems; }
        set
        {
            knownDeviceItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private KnownDevice selectedKnownDevice;
    public KnownDevice SelectedKnownDevice
    {
        get { return selectedKnownDevice; }
        set
        {
            selectedKnownDevice = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Thanks